# Eclipse debug: "Error in final sequence - Failed to execute MI command"

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I'm running Eclipse on win7. I want to make console applications that can run on either windows or linux. I followed the guide [here](http://www.tanzilli.com/foxg20_eclipse_windows_c) on how to setup the compiler

I'm trying to compile and run a simple hello world program. It compiles fine, but when I try to debug I get the following error:

```
'launching test' has encountered a problem.

Error in final launch sequence.
```

Clicking details reveals the following information.

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
```

My gdb debugger path is `C:\codesourcery\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe`

I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a windows console then I would think you would need gdb found in c:\minGW or wherever you have your Windows 7 gcc toolchain.

To change your debugger on Eclipse Kepler go to:
Run->Debug Configurations.  Select Debugger tab and in the "GDB debugger:" field, enter the path of your Windows gdb.exe file (c:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe if you're using minGW)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but hoping it will help someone. In my case, there was a breakpoint set with only a memory address (no file name associated with it). Not sure how I got into this situation... Once I removed the breakpoint, I was able to launch my program with debugger. Note, I am using Eclipse Luna CDT (SR2)

Comment: This should be a new question rather than an answer.

Comment: It's not a question though.